# HTTPS request with Python standard library

Tags: python, http, urllib, httplib

UPDATE: I managed to do a request with urllib2, but I'm still wondering what is happening here.

I would like to do a HTTPS request with Python.

This works fine with the requests module, but I don't want to use external dependencies, so I'd like to use the standard library.

**httplib**

When I follow [this example](https://docs.python.org/2.2/lib/httplib-examples.html) I don't get a response. I get a timeout instead. I'm out of ideas as to what would cause this.

Code:

```
import requests
print requests.get('https://python.org')

from httplib import HTTPSConnection
conn = HTTPSConnection('www.python.org')
conn.request('GET', '/index.html')
print conn.getresponse()
```

Output:

```
<Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn.request('GET', '/index.html')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1069, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1109, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1065, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 892, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1282, in connect
    HTTPConnection.connect(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 831, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

**urllib**

This fails for a different (but possibly related) reason. Code:

```
import urllib
print urllib.urlopen("https://python.org")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print urllib.urlopen("https://python.org")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 215, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 445, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1065, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 892, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1290, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 369, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 599, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 828, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:727)
```

What is requests doing that makes it succeed where both of these libraries fail?

Comment: Do you have to use Python 2?

Comment: Yes, and ideally it is also compatible with python 3

Answer (score 1):

`requests.get` without `timeout` parameter mean no timeout at all.
`httplib.HTTPSConnection` accept parameter `timeout` in `Python 2.6` and newer according to [httplib docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html). If your problem was caused by timeout, setting high enough timeout should help. Please try replacing:

```
conn = HTTPSConnection('www.python.org')
```

with:

```
conn = HTTPSConnection('www.python.org', timeout=300)
```

which will give 300 seconds (5 minutes) for processing.

Comment: This doesn't work. It just waits 300 seconds and then it gives the same error.